# imap - how to validate that complete message was transferred?

Tags: imap, checksum

Does IMAP protocol provide any way to validate / verify that complete message was transferred from the server to local client? i.e. is there any equivalent of ETag / MD5 or some other checksum?

Answer (score 1):

The IMAP protocol will tell you how many octets are going to be transfered when you issue the FETCH command. This should enable you to verify the completeness of the message. However, there is no command (AFAIK) that would provide any kind of checksum/hash functionality.